# How Can i Add More Then One Permission In This?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want a command to work for more than one permission than `MANAGE_MESSAGES`
How would I do that?
My code:

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_MESSAGES"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`GuildMember.hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) accepts a [`PermissionResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PermissionResolvable) as the first parameter, which can be an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

---

```js
if (message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_MESSAGES", "BAN_MEMBERS", "CONNECT"])) {
    // Code Here
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.hasPermission([parameter]) is an Array, so you can name more than one parameter,
if(message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_MESSAGES', 'KICK_MEMBERS', 'ETC']) {

/* Code */

}
```

Or you can make

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_MESSAGES', 'KICK_MEMBERS', 'ETC']) return;

/* this is for the members who dont have the permissions, ignore, if you want you can
add things to return, ex:*/

return message.channel.send('No permissions');
```

Comment: Thank You For The Help